# Validate that a file is present

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a JavaScript function that is looking to verify that one of two file inputs are populated, though at the moment I have an issue where validation will only work (i.e. the error message will hide) when only both input fields are populated.

Why would I be getting this?

```
function validateFileInput() {
    var ownImage = $('#fileField').val();
    console.log(ownImage);
    var defaultImage = $('#defImage').val();
    console.log(defaultImage);

    if (ownImage == "" || defaultImage == "") {
        $('#image_error').addClass('error-message');
        $(".error-message").css('display', 'inline-block');
        return false;
    } else {
        $('#image_error').removeClass('error-message');
        $("#image_error").css('display', 'none');
        return true;
    }
}
```

When logging to the console before the function is run I get

```
ownImage = ""
defaultImage = ""
```

When I then upload files to both fields I get the output below and validation passes

```
ownImage = "filename.jpg"
defaultImage = "4" // Im passing a data-attribute-id here
```

Whereas if I only upload one image, validation fails. I want validation to pass if either of the input fields have an upload.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want *either* to be populated then `if (ownImage == "" || defaultImage == "")` should be `if (ownImage == "" && defaultImage == "")`

i.e. only display the error message if x **and** y are empty. If either is populated then continue.

Comment: @Richlewis no, if you want that check, you need `if(ownImage != "" && defaultImage != "")`

Comment: Depends on your logic, you kind of have a double negative. You want to display an error message if both are empty. Might be easier to read if you invert the if.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, i can see and understand the logic now

Answer (score 2):

I think the line

```
if (ownImage == "" || defaultImage == "") {
```

should read

```
if (ownImage == "" && defaultImage == "") {
```

The first code will activate the error procedure, if **one of two** uploads is empty

The last code will activate the error procedure, if **both** uploads are empty

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
if (ownImage == "" && defaultImage == "")
```

It basically works like this

```
if (file1 is uploaded AND file2 is uploaded ){
//True only if Both conditions satisfied.
}
```

It checks if "ownImage" has No value AND  "defaultImage" also doesnt have any value.You used OR Boolean operator,which makes condition TRUE evenif only one condition is satisfied.